# Java error Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system

Tags: security, java, dell

I want to reboot a server, so I opened its Integreted Dell Remote Access Controller in Chrome, and clicked on "start virtual console", which caused Chrome to download a file with a strange name. The file opened in Java Web Launcher, which (after a while) gave the following error:

```
Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system
```

and:

```
The following resource is signed with a weak signature algorithm
MD5withRSA and is treated as unsigned
```

The detailed error message is:

```
    JNLPException[category: 安全错误 : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
    <jnlp codebase="https://192.168.8.208:443" spec="1.0+">
      <information>
        <title>iDRAC7 Virtual Console Client</title>
        <vendor>Dell Inc.</vendor>
        <icon href="https://192.168.8.208:443/images/logo.gif" kind="splash"/>
        <shortcut online="true"/>
      </information>
      <application-desc main-class="com.avocent.idrac.kvm.Main">
        <argument>ip=192.168.8.208</argument>
        <argument>vmprivilege=true</argument>
        <argument>helpurl=https://192.168.8.208:443/help/contents.html</argument>
        <argument>title=idrac-HB66YX1%2C+PowerEdge+M620%2C++%26%2325554%3B%26%2327133%3B+4%2C+%26%2329992%3B%26%2325143%3B%26%2365306%3B+root</argument>
        <argument>user=2114738097</argument>
        <argument>passwd=2007905771</argument>
        <argument>kmport=5900</argument>
        <argument>vport=5900</argument>
        <argument>apcp=1</argument>
        <argument>F2=1</argument>
        <argument>F1=1</argument>
        <argument>scaling=15</argument>
        <argument>minwinheight=100</argument>
        <argument>minwinwidth=100</argument>
        <argument>videoborder=0</argument>
        <argument>version=2</argument>
      </application-desc>
      <security>
        <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVM.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOWin32.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMWin32.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOWin64.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMWin64.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOWin64.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMWin64.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Linux" arch="i586">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Linux" arch="i686">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMLinux32.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMLinux64.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMLinux64.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
      <resources os="Mac OS X" arch="x86_64">
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctKVMIOMac64.jar" download="eager"/>
        <nativelib href="https://192.168.8.208:443/software/avctVMMac64.jar" download="eager"/>
      </resources>
    </jnlp> ]
        at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the `Java\jre\lib\security\java.security` file I changed the (default)

```
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
```

line, replacing '1024' with '128', and cleared all cache following the instructions given on this page:
https://www.blackmoreops.com/2017/06/08/fix-java-error-unsigned-application-requesting-unrestricted-access-to-system/

However, the application still won't load. Does anyone knows how to solve this situation?

Comment: You need to update your Dell DRAC Firmware to get a recently signed webstart application. It might not be possible with out-of-service hardware. If you want to get it to work remove MD5 from the disabled algorithms list.

Comment: I would **strongly** avoid allowing MD5 certificates, allowing attackers to create [fake certificates](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/downloads/md5-collisions-1.0.pdf)

Comment: @Geek2Sages  Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 13):

A quick way to fix this is to comment out the setting of `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms` in the file lib/security/java.security.

Comment this part:

```
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024
```

The path on windows is something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security.

Comment: On MacOSX the path of java.security for Safari can be found by going to the System Properties > Java. Click on the Java tab, then click View button to see the JRE details which includes the path. My file was at /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/java.security

Comment: This could be related just to the SHA1 algorithm. You likely have a `SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01` line within `java.security` (that is right after the above line in the answer) that can be commented out (put a # at the very beginning of that line) after you edit the above line (remove the , and \ to avoid the interpretation of the next line).  I kept the older algorithms disabled and SHA1 enabled this way so that I could run a legacy application that I am forced to run at work.

Comment: This helped, but then I got error "Failed to validate certificate". For solving that second error I also had to comment out configuration part starting with `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=`.

Answer (score 1):

update november 2022: comment for avoid alerts unsigned app

#, \     SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01

Answer (score 0):

iDRAC6 firmware version 1.98 solves this properly. I encountered this same error on iDRAC6 1.8

Obtain firmware `.d6` file:

- Goto [iDRAC 6 homepage](https://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/audhs1/sln311272/idrac6-home?lang=en)
- Choose `iDRAC6 Monolithic FW` or `iDRAC6 Blade FW`
- Download `iDRAC6_1.98_A00.exe`
- Use a windows computer to run the extractor
- Locate extracted file `firmimg.d6`

Upload the `firmimg.d6` file to the iDRAC firmware update page.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the server IP to the trusted sites in the Java control panel. To do this, start the control panel in Windows, click on Java (you might have to switch to icon view in order to see the Java icon). In the Java settings window, select the "Security" tab, and press the "Edit Site List..." button near the bottom of the window, below "Exception site list". Add your server to the trusted site list.

After this, Java should pop up a warning dialog, but allow you to continue.

If it does not, then your best bet is to install an older Java version (1.6) to access the iDRAC.

Also, you might want to check if there is a newer firmware for your server, as the current one seems a bit outdated.

Comment: I had to do what Lacek said. I tried disabling the security and it would not work. As soon as I installed 1.6 it worked like a charm.